# Proving matrix is invertible using the Banach Lemma

Tags: matrices

I have an assignment question that goes like this:

Consider the $n \times n$ matrix

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
      2 & 1 & 2^{-1} & 2^{-2} & 2^{-3} & 2^{-4} & \cdots & \cdots & 2^{-(n-2)} \\
      2^{-(n-2)} & 2 & 1 & 2^{-1} & 2^{-2} & 2^{-3} & \cdots & \cdots & 2^{-(n-3)} \\
      2^{-(n-3)} & 2^{-(n-2)} & 2 & 1 & 2^{-1} & 2^{-2} & \cdots & \cdots & 2^{-(n-4)} \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & & \vdots \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & & \vdots \\
      1 & 2^{-1} & 2^{-2} & 2^{-3} & 2^{-4} & 2^{-5} & \cdots & 2^{-(n-2)} & 2
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Write down this matrix for the case $n = 5$. Use the Banach Lemma (with the matrix infinity-norm) to show that $A_n$ is invertible for any positive integer $n$. Also use the Banach Lemma to derive a suitable upper bound on the infinity-norm of $A_n^{-1}$.

I figured out the matrix for $n= 5$. But after that, I have no idea how to solve this problem. Can someone explain it to me?

Thank you.

Comment: By "Banach lemma" do you mean this? $$$$ Let $\lVert\bullet\rVert$ an operator (i.e. sub-multiplicative) norm and $C$ a matrix such that $\lVert C\rVert<1$. Then $I-C$ is invertible and $\lVert(I-C)^{-1}\rVert\le 1/(I-\lVert C\rVert)$ $$$$

Comment: Exactly. I was about to edit that in. Sorry about that. However, in my notes, it says $I + C$. I don't know if that changes anything.

Comment: It's the same, you can pass from one to another using it on $B=-C$.

Comment: Alright, thank you for clarifying that for me.

Answer (score 1):

Scale the matrix by one half. The new matrix is less than one away from the identity matrix. Apply Banach and undo the scaling.

EDIT: Let $A$ denote your matrix. Then $S = \frac{1}{2}A$ has ones on the main diagonal. Moreover, along each row the off diagonal entries are the just the numbers
\begin{equation}
2^{-1}, 2^{-2}, \dotsc,  2^{-(n-1)}
\end{equation}
in some order. These numbers sum to $1 - 2^{-(n-1)}$ so 
\begin{equation}
\|S-I\|_\infty = 1 - 2^{-(n-1)} < 1.
\end{equation}
Now this is the critical point: By writing $S = I + (S-I)$ you can regard $S$ as a modest perturbation of the identity matrix. By Banach's lemma $S$ is non-singular and you can write
\begin{equation}
\|S^{-1}\|_\infty \leq \frac{1}{1 - \|I-S\|_\infty} = \frac{1}{1 - (1 - 2^{-(n-1)})} = 2^{n-1}.
\end{equation}
Since $A = 2S$ we have that $A$ is nonsingular, and an estimate of $\|A^{-1}\|_\infty$ follows quickly.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't follow. I'm not very good with matrices and the Banach Lemma proof.

Comment: I tried this but didn't have much luck. I might be doing something wrong. I'm not sure how to use the Banach Lemma.

Comment: Can you please explain? I'm hitting dead ends

Comment: I have added more information. Try to generalize to the situation where $A$ is non singular and $B$ is close to $A$ in the sense that the norm of $A^{-1}B-I$ is strict less than $1$. Write $B = A + (B-A) = A(I+A^{-1}(B-A))$ and see what can be deduced about the status of $B$!

Comment: Perfect! I will look into this. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure how to derive the upper bound on the matrix norm. How do we do that?

Comment: The sum is a  truncated geometric series. But better still is to think in terms of the binary expansion of the number 1. We have $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 2^{-k} = (0.111\dotsc1)_2$ in binary. If we add $1$ in the last place (or equivalently $2^{-(n-1)}$ then we obtain $2^{-(n-1)} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 2^{-k} = 1$.